# US to UK visa - suspended driving license

Tags: united-kingdom

My partner will be applying for a UK spouse visa after we marry next year.

He is in the US and had his driving license suspended for 3 months due to crashes with the work van last year.

He still doesn’t have his driving license, we hoped to apply in about 6 months. Will this go against him?

Comment: What kind of license was suspended? His driving license? A working license?

Comment: Driving license from crashes in works van

Comment: That makes more sense. I voted to edit your message to make clear it's a driving license.

Comment: Was he convicted of any driving offences?

Comment: No conviction just a suspension

Comment: @JorenVandamme because the first sound in "UK" is "you," the correct indefinite article is "a," not "an."

Comment: Who suspended his licence? If he wasn’t convicted of any driving offences I doubt very much that it will affect his spouse visa application https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal and even if he was, the offence would have to be significant for it to matter

Comment: @Confyooosed how was his license suspended without a conviction?  Note that accepting responsibility for a traffic ticket usually constitutes pleading guilty or "no contest" to a moving violation, which is legally speaking equivalent to a conviction.  Because of the US constitution's guarantee of due process, it's not generally permissible to suspend someone's license unless there's been a violation formally proven (or at least unchallenged) in traffic court or similar.

Comment: @phoog Dang I didn't know that. Today I learned. Thanks!

Comment: @JorenVandamme you're welcome.  It's a very common misapplication of the rule (dozens of examples on this site) that stems from the rule being taught in somewhat oversimplified terms (namely that teachers sometimes neglect to teach that "begins with a vowel" must be evaluated in phonetic terms rather than orthographically).  The only vowel that is really a problem is _u,_ of course, but there's also _h,_ where even native English speakers disagree about how to treat it when it isn't silent ("an history" or "a history"?).

Comment: Actually @phoog you are correct about the phonetic part, as in ‘it’s how the letter sounds’ rather than the letter itself. Because the U in UK sounds like ‘you’ the y part makes it ‘a’ not ‘an’. Just like the use before the letter H, if the word sounds like a hard ‘hu’ sound it is ‘a’ whereas if it is silent it is ‘an’. An honourable man, a history book. An umbrella, a UK national. I haven’t found teaching of the use of a or an to be taught incorrectly

Comment: @Confyooosed but traditionalists would write "an historic occasion."  For the indefinite article, indeed, perhaps it is not taught incorrectly.  I have no experience learning English as a foreign language.  But many people learn it incorrectly, and, more to the point, many people cite the rule incorrectly as "use 'an' before a vowel."

Comment: Valid point @phoog

Comment: You would either say “an-istoric-occasion” or “a-historic-occasion”, your choice. And I have an uncle wearing a uniform.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/criminal-records-checks-for-overseas-applicants/guidance-on-the-application-process-for-criminal-records-checks-overseas

> If you are applying for entry clearance under any of the following visa routes, you must provide a criminal record certificate for any country (excluding the UK) where you have lived for 12 months or more (whether continuous or in total), in the 10 years before your application, while aged 18 or over.

- Tier 1 (Entrepreneur)
- Tier 1 (Investor)
- Skilled Worker in education, health or social care sectors (see below)
- Dependent partner (over 18 years old) of the main applicant in any of the above routes, either together with the main applicant or separately

> **Visa applicants in all other routes are not currently required to provide criminal record certificates**. Also, those already in the UK seeking to extend their stay in one of the above categories are not presently included.

Emphasis mine.